# Find if a part of the integer from another integer is divisible by 7?

Tags: python, python-2.x, comparative-review, time-limit-exceeded

The question states:

> Given an integer A, and two indices Li, Ri. Find if the number from A which is bounded by the two indices is divisible by 7?
>
> For example if A = 357753
>   indices Li = 3, Ri = 4, then the number is 77, which is divisible.

My program give a time limit exceeded when executed for larger numbers. Are there any other performance improvement can be done in my code. Or the whole method is wrong for the solution. Any help would be appreciated. "q" is the number of indices that will be provided as input.

First code (not optimized):

```
inp = raw_input()

q = input()



temp = ""

for i in range(q):

    l, r = map(int, raw_input().split())

    temp =  int(inp[l - 1:r])

    if temp % 7 == 0:

        print "YES"
    else:

        print "NO"
```

My second program is:

```
inp = input()

q = input()

temp = 0
length = len(str(inp)) - 1
for i in range(q):

    left, right = map(int, raw_input().split())

    temp = inp
    end = length - right + 1
    temp = temp / (10 ** end)
    mul = 1
    final = 0

    while right >= left:

        cur = temp % 10
        temp = temp / 10
        right -= 1
        #print cur
        final += (cur * mul)
        mul = mul * 10


    if final % 7 == 0:

        print "YES"
    else:

        print "NO"
```

Comment: Some more information might be useful: In what number range are the given numbers? How many indices Li, Ri are given for a single number A? If this is a public challenge, can you provide a link?

Comment: What are your test numbers?

Comment: what does `q` do?

Comment: @OscarSmith `q` is the number of test cases.

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold because I suspect that it is part of an ongoing programming contest. I'll reopen it in a week (or earlier, if given evidence that it isn't). (See this [other question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/136461/9357) posted shortly after).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is a contest question, but it was ended 3 days before. When i searched for the problem link it was not available. I can remember only the question and when i tested the solution it came TLE for all inputs(almost 25, though the initial test cases were accepted). The "q" value is number of set of indices that will be provided as input. Sorry for not mentioning that in the question itself.

Comment: Reopened. Thanks for the clarification. If there is a link to the challenge online, that would be nice to add.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you think the second one is "optimized"; the former at least *looks* faster to me.

Don't name variables `temp` - it tells you nothing about the actual job of the variable. `q` is also a bad name'; `num_iters` is clearer, and `i` is not used so just use an underscore instead.

Don't pre-initialize values, in this case `temp`. Assign to it only when you need to.

Don't use `input` - *always* use `raw_input` and explicit conversions.

Then you have

```
inp = raw_input()
num_iters = int(raw_input())

for _ in range(num_iters):
    l, r = map(int, raw_input().split())
    temp = int(inp[l - 1:r])

    if temp % 7 == 0:
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

which is simple enough to basically be ideal. A more advanced programmer might want to handle errors or put code into functions, but the advantages of those only really apply to larger programs.

Comment: The one other thing I would add is don't name variables l. it looks like a 1, and thus can be quite confusing. I would suggest left or li (left index).

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my question. But, i don't know why it came as TLE for all inputs. And since it is a past contest it is not allowing to test it now. And i will definitely try to improve my coding method next time .

Comment: @susil95 You probably can't get much faster on CPython. Chances are the bottleneck is the `print`, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Does stdout write will give an speeder output? Because sometimes in contest they recommend to so that?

Comment: @susil95 Depending on how you do it, possibly. I'd have to time it to know for sure, though.

Comment: if you don't have to ouput all the yeses and nos at the same time, you could print them in groups at the end, which would be faster.